# How to split video into seconds and then show 1 second each time a user submits their email address

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a large video that runs in the background of my website. I want to split this video into seconds and then make 1 second of the video visible each time a user submits their email address. So, 1 submission = 1 second of the video. And you should only be able to submit a email address one time.

How do I achieve this? If someone could either hook me up with a tutorial or a plugin -- I will be forever grateful!

EDIT: I'm not a developer. Should make that clear. I'm kind of new to Javascript and haven't really tried that much yet -- because I simply don't know where to start.

Cheers

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Can you show us some of your code? How are you displaying the video, for example?

Comment: What is the business logic of user submitting the same email address multiple times (each time for each second of the video)? What do you try to achieve in plain words?

Comment: @Cerbus I editet the OP. I haven't tried that much yet, because I'm not sure where to begin. I'm currently using a WP-plugin called "mb.yt player" for the background video.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a HTML5 video tag. You can control it with Javascript. So we have a video, and a email submit input:

```
<!-- video player -->
<video controls id="my_vid" src="my_vid.mp4"></video>
<!-- email input -->
<input type="email" id="my_email" />
<!-- submit button -->
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="play_one_sec();" />
```

So basically what you can do is every time the user submit his email, you play the video one second with Javascript.

```
function play_one_sec()
{
   //get the video player
   var video = document.getElementById('my_vid');
   //play the video
   video.play();
   //one second later, pause it
   setTimeout(function() { video.pause(); }, 1000);
}
```

This should work, or at least give you a few hints.

Comment: use setTimeout instead of setInterval. setInterval here doesn't make any sense and it'll actually create unexpected behavior

Comment: oh yeah sorry, didn't pay enough attention ^^